# Using System.Windows.Size as universal "size" instead of UI controls size

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

It is appropriate to use System.Windows.Size for describing, for example, sizes of buildings in my app, or should I create my own structure for it? This domain has nothing to do with System.Windows or displays.

```
public struct Size
{
    public Size(double length, double width) : this()
    {
        Length = length;
        Width = width;
    }

    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tend to agree with @AccessDenied - System.Windows.Size might seem a good match (at the moment), but in the future you might want to add a height field, and possibly a lat/lon.  Then you may want to use .NET core, which doesn't have a cross platform System.Windows.   Just make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own struct since Size is platform specific. For example, Xamarin.Forms have different Size structure. 
And make your size [immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36780497/1099716). It's a [bad practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct) to create mutable structures.