# C# ImmutableObject attribute doesn't work, still can change struct value

Tags: c#, struct, immutability

It's said, a best practice is to make structs immutable, so I did this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int mI;
    public string mS;
}
[ImmutableObject(true)]
struct ComplexStruct
{
    public int mJ;
    public MyStruct st;
}
```

And the in main:

```
ComplexStruct cs = new ComplexStruct
{
    mJ = 6,
    st = new MyStruct
    {
        mI = 7,
        mS = "immutable"
    }
};
cs.st.mS = "Changed";
Console.WriteLine(cs.st.mS);
cs.st = new MyStruct
{
    mI = 8,
    mS = "check immutable?"
};
```

It compiles and runs well. What I expected is:

1. cs.st is a struct, and changing the cs.st.mS is using a copy of the value, and the content should not change to "Changed"?
2. I used Immutable attribute on "ComplexStruct", why still after initialization, I can change the "st" member struct?

I expected that compilation should fail, or there's runtime exception, because of using "Immutable". So why they don't work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does `ImmutableObject` do? Does it **document** what you have done? Or does it **do** something?

Comment: If you want an immutable object then don't use fields, use properties with a private setter and initialise them in the constructor. Voila, immutable objects.

Comment: I can see how it could confuse a developer that's inexperienced with the .Net framework, but the linked answer can help explain the point of this attribute.

Comment: @SteveTodd private setters does not make an object immutable. Missing setters do.

Comment: [Immutable struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36780200/1997232).