# System.Memory Slice Impure

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a class that has these 2 fields:

```
private readonly Memory<byte> data;
public Memory<byte> Reserved1 => data.Slice(0, 2);
```

ReSharper is giving me a warning with the `Slice`: *Impure method is called for readonly field of value type*

Removing `readonly` from the data declaration fixes the warning, but I'd like to understand if this warning is a false positive in this situation or if the warning is valid and I should avoid setting `data` `readonly`. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this correctly,

`Memory<T>` is a readonly struct anyway, and its fields are immutable. Though the memory it points to is not.

Mutations on the slice will be reflected in the memory it points to in `data`, which is what i assume you want. The warnings in this case can be ignored, with

```
 // ReSharper disable once ImpureMethodCallOnReadonlyValueField
```

Also there is a relatively famous question answered by *Jon Skeet*, and *Eric Lippert* talking about impure methods and their ramifications on structs

[Impure method is called for readonly field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927434/impure-method-is-called-for-readonly-field)